# Camel saves full http request but I want only attached file

Tags: java, rest, upload, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have the following code base:

```
@Component
public class DummyRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        rest("/upload").post().to("file://rest_files");
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
        SpringServerServlet serverServlet = new SpringServerServlet();
        ServletRegistrationBean regBean = new ServletRegistrationBean( serverServlet, "/rest/*");
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("org.restlet.component", "restletComponent");
        regBean.setInitParameters(params);
        return regBean;
    }


    @Bean
    public org.restlet.Component restletComponent() {
        return new org.restlet.Component();
    }

    @Bean
    public RestletComponent restletComponentService() {
        return new RestletComponent(restletComponent());
    }

}
```

I upload file using postman:

[image]

It is actually usual csv.

But when I open file my application stored - I see file with following content:

[image]

Obvious that file contains full request information.

How can I save only file without other data from http request?

**P.S.**

I tried to register callback:

```
 @Override
 public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
     System.out.println(exchange);
     final MultipartFile mandatoryBody = exchange.getIn().getBody(MultipartFile.class);
```

but it returns `null`

Comment: What version of Camel do you use? And have you tried latest release

Comment: @Claus Ibsen, CAMEL_VERSION = '2.20.0' looks like it is fresh enough

Comment: Look into the source code of camel-restlet and restlet api how file upload works with them - this component has been a pain to maintain as they are so different than others

Comment: Can point me in more specific places? I am novice in camel

Comment: @gstackoverflow, did you find some work-around to it?

Comment: I have answered almost identical question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54207451/8576169