# Camel Rest DSL retrieve HTTP POST multipart File

Tags: rest, http, spring-boot, apache-camel, postman

My Router class looks like below and i am trying to upload a video file and store it to a File location.

**SpringBootRouter.java**

```
package com.camelrest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletComponent;
import org.apache.camel.spring.boot.FatJarRouter;
import org.restlet.Component;
import org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringServerServlet;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MySpringBootRouter extends FatJarRouter {

    @Autowired
    private MultipartProcessor multipartProcessor;

    @Override
    public void configure() {

        restConfiguration().component("restlet");

        rest("/upload").post().to("direct:upload");

        from("direct:upload")
        .to("file://E:/RestTest");

    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {

        SpringServerServlet serverServlet = new SpringServerServlet();
        ServletRegistrationBean regBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(
                serverServlet, "/rest/*");

        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

        params.put("org.restlet.component", "restletComponent");

        regBean.setInitParameters(params);

        return regBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public Component restletComponent() {
        return new Component();
    }

    @Bean
    public RestletComponent restletComponentService() {
        return new RestletComponent(restletComponent());
    }    
}
```

I am trying to upload a video file using postman as per below screenshot :

[image]

My contents of the file that i upload are saved with a file name with some random camel ID generated by camel

[image]

However i want the filename that is passed in body

> SampleVideo_1280x720_10mb.mp4

to be the name of the file and remove the following contents from the body

```
----------------------------948281627232093197119960
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="SampleVideo_1280x720_10mb.mp4"
Content-Type: video/mp4
```

So final output can be the video uploaded with the filename used during the upload with postman

Comment: You will need to create a bean or processor to extract the name. try to look into commons fileupload  https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/streaming.html.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`MimeMultipartDataFormat`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.23.0/org/apache/camel/model/dataformat/MimeMultipartDataFormat.html) to unmarshal Multipart request. Using this, will prepare attachments, to [`Exchange`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.23.0/org/apache/camel/Exchange.html).

After that you need somehow convert [`Attachment`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.23.0/org/apache/camel/Attachment.html) to `InputStream` and fill `CamelFileName` header. With this task can help you small `Processor`.

**Route:**

```
from("direct:upload")
        .unmarshal().mimeMultipart().split().attachments()
        .process(new PrepareFileFromAttachment())
        .to("file://C:/RestTest");
```

**Processor:**

```
class PrepareFileFromAttachment implements Processor {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        DataHandler dataHandler = exchange.getIn().getBody(Attachment.class).getDataHandler();
        exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, dataHandler.getName());
        exchange.getIn().setBody(dataHandler.getInputStream());
    }
}
```

---

The approach above does not work in case your form contains only single input in form. This is because [`MimeMultipartDataFormat`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.23.0/org/apache/camel/model/dataformat/MimeMultipartDataFormat.html) marshals first form input into body (without storing file name) and other inputs to attachments where the file name is stored. 
In this case you need to create `Processor` reading `InputStream` directly:

**Route:**

```
from("direct:upload")
        .process(new ProcessMultipartRequest())
        .to("file:c://RestTest");
```

**Processor**

```
public class ProcessMultipartRequest implements Processor {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        InputStream is = exchange.getIn().getBody(InputStream.class);
        MimeBodyPart mimeMessage = new MimeBodyPart(is);
        DataHandler dh = mimeMessage.getDataHandler();
        exchange.getIn().setBody(dh.getInputStream());
        exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, dh.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your insight. 
The .attachments() is returning null when i put debugger this line :
DataHandler dataHandler = exchange.getIn().getBody(Attachment.class).getDataHandler(); returns null. Can you please suggest some other way to get the FileName now the body sets the video and am able to see the Video in postman but not able to get the filename of the uploaded video. Please suggest me to get around.

Comment: I see. This approach works only if your post contains any other key in form in postman. When form post contains only file key, it is marshalled directly to body, instead of attachment. I am debugging what is going on in `MimeMultipartDataFormat`.

Comment: After debugging I see, the first part of request is always stored in `body` and in this case, the file name is lost. It is stored only to other keys in attachments. I have edited answer with explanation and alternative implementation for single key forms.

Comment: Awesome answer i was struggling with this for sometime, thank you so much. Can you throw some light into multipart data if we need to process more than one key like upload a file and pass other values in body. That would also really help....

Answer (score 0):

In multipart/form-data request order of fields matter. File field should be first in order while submitting. Apache camel creates attachment objects of all fields except the first one in your request.
For eg.
[Multipart Form data Postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTinY.jpg)

Other fields:

- var1 and var2 become attachment objects

```
    from(route)
        .unmarshal().mimeMultipart().split().attachments()
        .log("process")
        .end()
        .process(new MyProcessor())
        .end();
```

```
    public class MyProcessor implements Processor {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            // Other field values
            Collection<Attachment> attachments = exchange.getIn().getAttachmentObjects().values();
            for(Attachment attachment : attachments){
                // attachment value
                attachment.getDataHandler().getInputStream();
            }
            // Body of request file content
            InputStream is = exchange.getIn().getBody(InputStream.class);
        }
    }
```