# Uploading a file to Camel Rest route

Tags: apache-camel, multipartform-data

I'm trying to upload a file using multipart/form-data to a Camel route.
All is good, however, I can't get the original file name.
Camel version is: 3.14.1

**Update**
With the following modification to the route. I managed to process binary files (getting the file name and storing them). However, with text files, the file is appended with the boundary footer:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary7BH9nQ2RqDXvTRAJ--
```

The route definition:

```
        rest("/v1/file-upload-form")
            .post()
            .consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
            .route()
            .process((exchange) -> {
                InputStream is = exchange.getIn().getBody(InputStream.class);
                MimeBodyPart mimeMessage = new MimeBodyPart(is);
                DataHandler dh = mimeMessage.getDataHandler();
                exchange.getIn().setBody(dh.getInputStream());
                exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, dh.getName());
            })
            .to("file://" + incomingFolder);
```

Thank you in advance

Edwardo

Comment: Have you tried to do the same thing as this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54207451/1997376?

Answer (score -1):

Edit: Since you have everything else already working, I'd recommend the Stream Caching option.

As Nicolas [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71640323/uploading-a-file-to-camel-rest-route#comment126629851_71640323), checkout Camel's MIME Multipart [data format](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.14.x/dataformats/mime-multipart-dataformat.html).

Also, the reason you're getting "Missing start boundary" is because your processor is consuming the InputStream. You can try to `reset()` it, but it might be better to just consume the InputStream once, or enable [Stream Caching](https://camel.apache.org/manual/stream-caching.html).

Instead of stream caching, you could also just convert the stream to a string. Before your processor, add:

```
.convertBodyTo(String.class)
```

The string can be read over and over. If you still get the missing start boundary error, try logging the body before the unmarshal operation. Make sure the message is intact and that it indeed contains the start boundary.

Comment: Stream cache is enabled at the context level, but the result is the same.
Could you elaborate on the " Stream Caching option" ?

Comment: Your processor burns the input stream when it gets the file name. Stream caching is a utility Camel has that allows the stream to be replayed. In this case, the unmarshal operation relies on stream caching to allow the input stream to be replayed. I'll update my answer with another option and some debugging tips.

Comment: thank you Jeremy, this is all good and known and as I mentioned I do enabled the streamCaching. However the result is the same as I stated (and converting to String didn't aid either).
Would you be able to have it working, if so can you post the complete route definition ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Before the unmarshal, log the body and see if it looks right and contains the start boundayr.

Comment: No, it doesn't therefore, the unmarshal failed. So it is, either unmarshal or getting the file name ;-(. Must be a better way. Further ideas?

Comment: Can you provide the content you're unmarshaling?

Comment: it is just a simple text file, but the same method should work for binary content.
And thank you in advance for your help